# Image Uploading in ASP.NET with C#

Tags: asp.net

I created 2 pages: page1.aspx and page2.aspx. I defined 5 fileuploader controls in page 2 but I want to save Page1.aspx on save button.

Actually, the page contains a Back Button in which I store all Uploading file in a string object and it populate on Page1.aspx as a session.

How can I save a file on server?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links which can help you out with this:

1) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/multiuploads.aspx

2) http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=68&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

3) http://www.asp.net/Learn/videos/video-252.aspx

Also couple of things to remember, the user associated with ASP.net account should have sufficient permissions on the server folder on which you are uploading the file to and the maximum size of the file is 4MB by default but you could change that using the web.config httpRuntime configuration changes.

Hope this would help,

Jomit